# Error while building qt project for android

Tags: android, qt

I downloaded Qt Creator 3.3.0 Based on Qt 5.4.0 on Windows.
Also jdk1.8.0_25, SDK (all updated), NDK-r10d, apache-ant-1.9.4.
Set all necessary configurations.
But when I try to build project I get an error:

> Error: Target id 'android--1' is not valid.

As far as I understand it is about the API level. But where can I set it?

Comment: Downvoted. Provide a more in-depth explanation and the exact error. Did you just built it or tried to run? Improve the question with all the necessary info.

Comment: The building stops at 4 from 5. I don't think the problem in deployment, because before that I tried **Android Studio** and everything works.

Comment: Now I should return to this question. Although, the decision have been found and it is still the same, you should reinstall JDK, it is not an answer on the question. I have tried to create different projects just to study Qt, but today when I created another one I have got the same result as I had a week ago. But today I already have working projects and I found the difference. Qt project has an auto generated file: PROJECT_NAME.pro.user and there you can find the strings 'android--1', so you should change all of them to 'android-21' (depends on your SDK version) and the project will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since Qt 5.4 along with QtCreator 3.3.0 you should go to **Projects > Build Android APK > Details** for configuring deployment settings. Select an Android API version for **Android Build SDK** option. Also to create an APK package, select the **Bundle Qt libraries in APK** option :

[image]

You can also select **Create Templates** to create the manifest file to set application settings like icon, name, ...

Comment: Yes, I thought about **Android Build SDK** option, but there is no items in that combobox.  Does it mean that I shoud install something in SDK?

Comment: Have you installed Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools when updating SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled JDK and now everything works.
I don't know definitely, but I think the problem had been obtained after update JDK from 1.8.0_25 to 1.8.0_31. The folder with previous version for some reason still was there. It was like:

> ..\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
>
> ..\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

And Qt refered to the jdk1.8.0_25 which already was obsolete.

Comment: It is incorrect answer, but removing and installation JDK really helps.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me - switch off antivirus. Why? See below:

I've got the same error and re-installation didn't help.

Running manually `android.bat list targets` from cmd gives the proper list of targets.

After digging into `QtCreator` code, I found the reason - magic code for get list of targets in `qt`:

```
void AndroidConfig::updateAvailableSdkPlatforms() const
{
    QProcess proc;
    proc.setProcessEnvironment(androidToolEnvironment().toProcessEnvironment());
    proc.start(androidToolPath().toString(), QStringList() << QLatin1String("list") << QLatin1String("target")); // list avaialbe AVDs
    if (!proc.waitForFinished(10000)) {
        proc.terminate();
        return;
    }
}
```

As you can see if `android.bat list target` cmd will not finish for 10 seconds, `qtcreator` will just terminate the process.

In my case it was 15 secs befor it finishes due to antivirus checks - so switching off antivirus could help in your case.

No need to restart `QtCreator`. Just open *Android* section in *options* again and all targets should be loaded.

I 'love' Qt - it is always like this with it.