# QtCreator building Android apk is failing with wrong SDK version

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

I followed the steps shown [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html). 
Installed JDK, Android SDK and NDK. Installed gradle, ant and OpenGl libraries.

When trying to build any android example I get the following error:

> Error: Target id 'android--1' is not valid.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684857/how-can-i-change-the-android-platform-in-qt-creator-to-not-be-android-1-in-de) but I couldn't select any API. The paths are all correctly set. Using NDK 10 since 14 has [known issues](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues).
I verified that it is not a timeout issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419098/error-while-building-qt-project-for-android)

Anyone encountering the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for not building is [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html):

> SDK Tools, Revision 25.3.0 (March 2017)
>
> Obsolete/deprecated tools have been removed:
>
> - android

QtCreator is using the tools to get information about the Android SDK. Workaround is to get the previous version (e.g. [25.2.5](http://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.de/p/android-sdk-tools.html)).

Comment: This was the only thing that actually worked  for me after pulling my hairs out on api level 22, at least somewhat.. It still doesn't detect the emulator correctly, so I cannot deploy to it or debug. But I can build at least and produce an APK. I wonder if anyone really has gotten the OREO api 22 to work properly even in the newest Qt SDK/Tools (5.9).

Comment: @Larswad There is a slack channel for Qt/Android development, you should go there if you need brand new infos: https://qtmob.slack.com/messages/C204H1U11/